# OpenGL program error. need help

Tags: opengl

```
//
// This code was created by Lionel Brits / Jeff Molofee '99
//
// If you've found this code useful, please let me know.
//
// Visit NeHe Productions at www.demonews.com/hosted/nehe
//
/**************************************************************/
// This code was ported to MacOS by Tony Parker.
//  I'd also appreciate it if you could drop me a line if you found
//  this code useful. 
// 
//  Tony Parker - asp@usc.edu
// 
// Have a nice day.

#include <stdio.h>          // Header File For Standard Input / Output
#include <stdarg.h>         // Header File For Variable Argument Routines
#include <string.h>         // Header File For String Management
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>              // Header File For The OpenGL32 Library
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>         // Header File For The GLu32 Library
#include <GLUT/glut.h>          // Header File For The GLUT Library

#include "math.h"

#include "model.h" 

// Constants ----------------------------------------------------------------------

#define kWindowHeight   400
#define kWindowWidth    400

// Structures ----------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct              // Create A Structure
{
    GLubyte *imageData;     // Image Data (Up To 32 Bits)
    GLuint  bpp;            // Image Color Depth In Bits Per Pixel.
    GLuint  width;          // Image Width
    GLuint  height;         // Image Height
    GLuint  texID;          // Texture ID Used To Select A Texture
} TextureImage;             // Structure Name

// Function Prototypes -------------------------------------------------------

bool LoadTGA(TextureImage *texture, char *filename);
float rad(float angle);
void readstr(FILE *f,char *string);
void SetupWorld(void);

GLvoid InitGL(GLvoid);
GLvoid DrawGLScene(GLvoid);
GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(int Width, int Height);
GLvoid Idle(GLvoid);
GLvoid LoadGLTextures(void);
GLvoid Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);

// Global Variables ----------------------------------------------------------

char        *worldfile = "world.txt";
bool        light;                      // Lighting ON/OFF
bool        gBlend;                     // Blending ON/OFF

GLfloat     xrot;                       // X Rotation
GLfloat     yrot;                       // Y Rotation
GLfloat     xspeed;                     // X Rotation Speed
GLfloat     yspeed;                     // Y Rotation Speed

GLfloat     walkbias = 0;
GLfloat     walkbiasangle = 0;

GLfloat     lookupdown = 0.0f;
const float piover180 = 0.0174532925f;

float       heading, xpos, zpos;

GLfloat     camx=0, camy=0, camz=0;     // Camera Location
GLfloat     therotate;

GLfloat     z=0.0f;                     // Depth Into The Screen

GLfloat     LightAmbient[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };        // Ambient Light
GLfloat     LightDiffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };        // Diffuse Light
GLfloat     LightPosition[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f };       // Light Position

GLuint      filter;         // Which Filter To Use
TextureImage texture[3];        // Storage for 3 textures

// Our Model Goes Here:
SECTOR      sector1;

// rad -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Converts Degrees To Radians. There Are 2 PI Radians In 360 Degrees.

float rad(float angle)
{
    return angle * piover180;
}

// readstr -------------------------------------------------------------------

void readstr(FILE *f,char *string)
{
    do
    {
        fgets(string, 255, f);
    } while ((string[0] == '/') || (string[0] == '\n'));
    return;
}

// SetupWorld ----------------------------------------------------------------

void SetupWorld(void)
{
    float x, y, z, u, v;
    int numtriangles;
    FILE *filein;
    char oneline[255];
    filein = fopen(worldfile, "rt");

    readstr(filein,oneline);
    sscanf(oneline, "NUMPOLLIES %d\n", &numtriangles);

    sector1.triangle = new TRIANGLE[numtriangles];
    sector1.numtriangles = numtriangles;
    int loop;
    for ( loop = 0; loop < numtriangles; loop++)
    {
        int vert;
        for ( vert = 0; vert < 3; vert++)
        {
            readstr(filein,oneline);
            sscanf(oneline, "%f %f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &u, &v);
            sector1.triangle[loop].vertex[vert].x = x;
            sector1.triangle[loop].vertex[vert].y = y;
            sector1.triangle[loop].vertex[vert].z = z;
            sector1.triangle[loop].vertex[vert].u = u;
            sector1.triangle[loop].vertex[vert].v = v;
        }
    }
    fclose(filein);
    return;
}


#pragma mark -

// Main ----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(kWindowWidth, kWindowHeight); 
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

    SetupWorld();
    InitGL();

    glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLScene); 
    glutReshapeFunc(ReSizeGLScene);

    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

// InitGL ---------------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid InitGL(GLvoid)
{

    LoadGLTextures();                                   // Load The Texture ( ADD )
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                            // Enable Texture Mapping ( ADD )

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);               // This Will Clear The Background Color To Black
    glClearDepth(1.0);                                  // Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enables Smooth Color Shading

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                        // Select The Projection Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Projection Matrix

    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat) kWindowWidth / (GLfloat) kWindowHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);  
                                                        // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                         // Select The Modelview Matrix

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, LightAmbient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, LightDiffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION,LightPosition);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
}

// Idle ---------------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid Idle(GLvoid)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Keyboard -----------------------------------------------------------------

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
#pragma unused (x, y)

    switch(key)
    {

        case 'b':       // turn blending on/off
        gBlend = !gBlend;
        if (!gBlend)
        {
            glDisable(GL_BLEND);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }
        else
        {
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }
        break;

        case 'f':       
        filter+=1;
        if (filter > 2)
        {
            filter = 0;
        }
        break;

        case 'l':
        light = !light;
        if (!light)
            glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        else
            glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        break;

        case 'w':       // walk forward
        xpos -= (float)sin(heading*piover180) * 0.05f;
        zpos -= (float)cos(heading*piover180) * 0.05f;

        if (walkbiasangle >= 359.0f)
            walkbiasangle = 0.0f;
        else 
            walkbiasangle+= 10;

        walkbias = (float)sin(walkbiasangle * piover180)/20.0f;

        //lookupdown -= 1.0f;

        break;

        case 'x':       // walk back
        xpos += (float)sin(heading*piover180) * 0.05f;
        zpos += (float)cos(heading*piover180) * 0.05f;
        if (walkbiasangle <= 1.0f)
            walkbiasangle = 359.0f;
        else 
            walkbiasangle-= 10;

        walkbias = (float)sin(walkbiasangle * piover180)/20.0f;

        //lookupdown += 1.0f;

        break;

        case 'd':       // turn right
        heading -= 1.0f;
        yrot = heading;
        break;

        case 'a':       // turn left
        heading += 1.0f;    
        yrot = heading;
        break;

        case 'q':
        z += 0.02f;
        break;

        case 'z':
        z += 0.02f;
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}


// DrawGLScene -------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid DrawGLScene(GLvoid)
{    

    GLfloat x_m, y_m, z_m, u_m, v_m;
    GLfloat xtrans, ztrans, ytrans;
    GLfloat sceneroty;

    xtrans = -xpos;
    ztrans = -zpos;
    ytrans = -walkbias-0.25f;

    sceneroty = 360.0f- yrot;


    int numtriangles;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();                                       // Reset The View

    glRotatef(lookupdown,1.0f,0,0);
    glRotatef(sceneroty,0,1.0f,0);

    glTranslatef(xtrans, ytrans, ztrans);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[filter].texID);


    numtriangles = sector1.numtriangles;

    // Process Each Triangle
    int loop_m;
    for ( loop_m = 0; loop_m < numtriangles; loop_m++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glNormal3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            x_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[0].x;
            y_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[0].y;
            z_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[0].z;
            u_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[0].u;
            v_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[0].v;
            glTexCoord2f(u_m,v_m); glVertex3f(x_m,y_m,z_m);

            x_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[1].x;
            y_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[1].y;
            z_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[1].z;
            u_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[1].u;
            v_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[1].v;
            glTexCoord2f(u_m,v_m); glVertex3f(x_m,y_m,z_m);

            x_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[2].x;
            y_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[2].y;
            z_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[2].z;
            u_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[2].u;
            v_m = sector1.triangle[loop_m].vertex[2].v;
            glTexCoord2f(u_m,v_m); glVertex3f(x_m,y_m,z_m);
        glEnd();
    }


    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

// ReSizeGLScene ------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(int Width, int Height)
{
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) Width, (GLsizei) Height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0, (GLfloat) Width / (GLfloat) Height, 0.1, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}


// LoadGLTextures ------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid LoadGLTextures(GLvoid)
{

    //load texture

    LoadTGA(&texture[0], "mud.tga");
    LoadTGA(&texture[1], "mud.tga");
    LoadTGA(&texture[2], "mud.tga");


    // Create Nearest Filtered Texture

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0].texID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture1->sizeX, texture1->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture1->data);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texture[0].width, texture[0].height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[0].imageData);

    // Create Linear Filtered Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1].texID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture1->sizeX, texture1->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture1->data);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texture[1].width, texture[1].height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[1].imageData);

    // Create MipMapped Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2].texID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, texture[2].width, texture[2].height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[2].imageData);

}


/********************> LoadTGA() <*****/
bool LoadTGA(TextureImage *texture, char *filename)         // Loads A TGA File Into Memory
{    
    GLubyte     TGAheader[12]={0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};    // Uncompressed TGA Header
    GLubyte     TGAcompare[12];                             // Used To Compare TGA Header
    GLubyte     header[6];                                  // First 6 Useful Bytes From The Header
    GLuint      bytesPerPixel;                              // Holds Number Of Bytes Per Pixel Used In The TGA File
    GLuint      imageSize;                                  // Used To Store The Image Size When Setting Aside Ram
    GLuint      temp;                                       // Temporary Variable
    GLuint      type=GL_RGBA;                               // Set The Default GL Mode To RBGA (32 BPP)

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");                     // Open The TGA File

    if( file==NULL ||                                       // Does File Even Exist?
        fread(TGAcompare,1,sizeof(TGAcompare),file)!=sizeof(TGAcompare) ||  // Are There 12 Bytes To Read?
        memcmp(TGAheader,TGAcompare,sizeof(TGAheader))!=0               ||  // Does The Header Match What We Want?
        fread(header,1,sizeof(header),file)!=sizeof(header))                // If So Read Next 6 Header Bytes
    {
        fclose(file);                                       // If Anything Failed, Close The File
        return false;                                       // Return False
    }

    texture->width  = header[1] * 256 + header[0];          // Determine The TGA Width  (highbyte*256+lowbyte)
    texture->height = header[3] * 256 + header[2];          // Determine The TGA Height (highbyte*256+lowbyte)

    if( texture->width  <=0 ||                              // Is The Width Less Than Or Equal To Zero
        texture->height <=0 ||                              // Is The Height Less Than Or Equal To Zero
        (header[4]!=24 && header[4]!=32))                   // Is The TGA 24 or 32 Bit?
    {
        fclose(file);                                       // If Anything Failed, Close The File
        return false;                                       // Return False
    }

    texture->bpp    = header[4];                            // Grab The TGA's Bits Per Pixel (24 or 32)
    bytesPerPixel   = texture->bpp/8;                       // Divide By 8 To Get The Bytes Per Pixel
    imageSize       = texture->width*texture->height*bytesPerPixel; // Calculate The Memory Required For The TGA Data

    texture->imageData=(GLubyte *)malloc(imageSize);        // Reserve Memory To Hold The TGA Data

    if( texture->imageData==NULL ||                         // Does The Storage Memory Exist?
        fread(texture->imageData, 1, imageSize, file)!=imageSize)   // Does The Image Size Match The Memory Reserved?
    {
        if(texture->imageData!=NULL)                        // Was Image Data Loaded
            free(texture->imageData);                       // If So, Release The Image Data

        fclose(file);                                       // Close The File
        return false;                                       // Return False
    }

    GLuint i;
    for( i=0; i<imageSize; i= i + bytesPerPixel)        // Loop Through The Image Data
    {                                                       // Swaps The 1st And 3rd Bytes ('R'ed and 'B'lue)
        temp=texture->imageData[i];                         // Temporarily Store The Value At Image Data 'i'
        texture->imageData[i] = texture->imageData[i + 2];  // Set The 1st Byte To The Value Of The 3rd Byte
        texture->imageData[i + 2] = temp;                   // Set The 3rd Byte To The Value In 'temp' (1st Byte Value)
    }

    fclose (file);                                          // Close The File

    if (texture[0].bpp==24)                                 // Was The TGA 24 Bits
    {
        type=GL_RGB;                                        // If So Set The 'type' To GL_RGB
    }

    // Build A Texture From The Data
    // We're doing this in a different function in this tutorial

    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0].texID);                    // Generate OpenGL texture IDs
    /*
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0].texID);         // Bind Our Texture
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   // Linear Filtered
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   // Linear Filtered

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, type, texture[0].width, texture[0].height, 0, type, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[0].imageData);
    */

    return true;                                            // Texture Building Went Ok, Return True
}
```

NEED HELP.
I got this error:

> /Users/***/Desktop/XcodeGLUT/../gora.cs.illinois.edu:display:cs418sp11:Home/Lesson
>   10 Folder/main.c:126:0
>   /Users/***/Desktop/XcodeGLUT/../gora.cs.illinois.edu:display:cs418sp11:Home/Lesson
>   10 Folder/main.c:126: error: 'new'
>   undeclared (first use in this
>   function)

Comment: Program's extension is `.c`. And there is no keyword called `new` in `C`. It seems `TRIANGLE` is a class, so try renaming the program as `main.cc` and build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename the file to main.cpp, seems the file is compiled using the c-compiler and not the C++ compiler where new is a keyword for allocating on the heap (instead of malloc/calloc)